# Do experience orbs disappear if you don't collect them?

Tags: fable-2

In Fable II (and I, and presumably III), killing enemies results in them dropping experience orbs, which you collect by holding the right trigger (default layout on the Xbox 360).

I'm curious whether or not these orbs will disappear over time, or they just wait to be called.  Can you "lose" experience this way?

Comment: In Fable (1), yes that's exactly what happens, exp is "lost". Don't know about fable 2 specifically, though

Comment: It seems like they just merge together into one larger orb. Check out this thread on Gamespot.com: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/927246-fable-ii/47724780 and this one: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/927246-fable-ii/46112298